# Is it possible to call AppDelegate UIApplication from the xcode notification service extension?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, react-native

I am working on a chat app using react-native in iOS. I want to do badge increment for every notification. When the app is inactive, Is it possible to call `AppDelegate UIApplication` from the notification service extension?

Answer (score 1):

Just set the push content "badge" : "+1"

Comment: u can use third-party push service to handle this. Or record a badge value for each device in your server, synchronize it when app is open or badge changed, this is just what the third-party does. And I just thought out another way, maybe you can store badge value in keychain or database, then read and change it in notification extension.

Comment: save the badge in keychain or userdefaults, add a field in push content's userInfo such as "increment" : true, then read badge value and change it in extension.